Classification task for tissue dataset
Does anyone work on classification problem for microscopy tissue dataset? The class is based on the rank-score (1-3) by the expert, where 1 is bad and 3 is good. Some of the images are blurry and have similar texture, each of the class has less than 200 images.
I tried resnet and efficientnet, the results show that resnet has better performace compared to efficientnet (accuracy around 60%), however both models can't classify score 2. The confusion matrix shows that the score 2 is classified as score 1 or score 3. The confusion matrix shows that the score 2 is classified as score 1 or score 3. Is there any suggestion to improve the accuracy besides adding more samples? Any sanity check need to be done to see whether the dataset is useful for this task?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
